# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' - bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I just wrote a bash script and always getting this EOF-Error.

So here is my script (only works on OS X):

```
#!/bin/bash

#DEFINITIONS BEGIN
en_sq() {
    echo -e "Enabling smart quotes..."
    defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool true
    status=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool)
            if [ "$status" = "1" ]
                then
                    echo -e "Success! Smart quotes are now enabled."
                    SUCCESS="TRUE"
            else
                echo -e "Sorry, an error occured. Try again."
            fi
}
di_sq() {
    echo -e "Disabling smart quotes..."
    defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool false
    status=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool)
            if [ "$status" = "0" ]
                then
                    echo -e "Success! Smart quotes are now disabled."
                    SUCCESS="TRUE"
            else
                echo -e "Sorry, an error occured. Try again."
            fi
}
en_sd() {
    echo -e "Enabling smart dashes..."
    defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled -bool true
    status=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled -bool)
            if [ "$status" = "1" ]
                then
                    echo -e "Success! Smart dashes are now enabled."
                    SUCCESS="TRUE"
            else
                echo -e "Sorry, an error occured. Try again."
            fi
}
di_sd() {
    echo -e "Enabling smart dashes..."
    defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled -bool false
    status=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled -bool)
            if [ "$status" = "0" ]
                then
                    echo -e "Success! Smart dashes are now disabled."
                    SUCCESS="TRUE"
            else
                echo -e "Sorry, an error occured. Try again."
            fi
}
#DEFINITIONS END
#---------------

#BEGIN OF CODE with properties
#This is only terminated if the user entered properties (eg ./sqd.sh 1 1)
if [ "$1" = "1" ]
    then
        en_sq
    elif [ "$1" = "0" ]
        then
            di_sq
fi

if [ "$2" = "1" ]
    then
        en_sd
        #exit 0 if both, $1 and $2 are correct entered and processed.
        exit 0
    elif [ "$1" = "0" ]
        then
            di_sd
            #exit 0 if both, $1 and $2 are correct entered and processed.
            exit 0
fi
#END OF CODE with properties
#---------------------------


#BEGIN OF CODE without properties
#This is terminated if the user didn't enter two properties
echo -e "\n\n\n\n\nINFO: You can use this command as following: $0 x y, while x and y can be either 0 for false or 1 for true."
echo -e "x is for the smart quotes, y for the smart dashes."
sleep 1
echo -e " \n Reading preferences...\n"
status=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool)
if [ "$status" = "1" ]
    then
        echo -e "Smart quotes are enabled."
    elif [ "$status" = "0" ]
    then
        echo -e "Smart quotes are disabled."

    else
        echo -e "Sorry, an error occured. You have to run this on OS X""
fi

status=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool)
if [ "$status" = "1" ]
    then
        echo -e "Smart dashes are enabled."
    elif [ "$status" = "0" ]
    then
        echo -e "Smart dashes are disabled."

    else
        echo -e "Sorry, an error occured. You have to run this on OS X!"
fi

sleep 3
echo -e "\n\n You can now enable or disable smart quotes."

until [ "$SUCCESS" = "TRUE" ]
do
echo -e "Enter e for enable or d for disable:"
read sq

if [ "$sq" = "e" ]
    then
        en_sq
    elif [ "$sq" = "d" ]
        then
            di_sq
    else
        echo -e "\n\n ERROR! Please enter e for enable or d for disable!"
fi
done
SUCCESS="FALSE"

echo -e "\n\n You can now enable or disable smart dashes."

until [ "$SUCCESS" = "TRUE" ]
do
echo -e "Enter e for enable or d for disable:"
read sq

if [ "$sd" = "e" ]
    then
        en_sd
    elif [ "$sd" = "d" ]
        then
            di_sd
    else
        echo -e "\n\n ERROR! Please enter e for enable or d for disable!"
fi
done
```

And here is my error:

```
./coding.sh: line 144: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./coding.sh: line 147: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can see your problem if you just look at your question. Note how the syntax highlighting is messed up after line 95:

```
echo -e "Sorry, an error occurred. You have to run this on OS X""
```

As the error message tells you, you have an unmatched `"`. Just remove the extra `"` from the line above and you should be fine:

```
echo -e "Sorry, an error occurred. You have to run this on OS X"
```

Comment: Strangely, I had the same problem and it was because I had a `sudo echo ""` line.. Removing the 2 double quotes, leaving `sudo echo` makes it work perfectly.

Comment: @vinzee why would you ever run `echo` with `sudo`? That said, what you describe doesn't make much sense, there must have been something else going on.

Comment: I do `sudo echo` because the script will need `sudo` later in the commands but I want the user to enter his password early on, so that the script does not need his input anymore for a few minutes.
And for the bug, I had the same error as seen here, but it was solved by removing the 2 double quotes. Nothing else happened..

Comment: @vinzee you might want to read [How do I run a 'sudo' command inside a script?](//askubuntu.com/q/425754). As for the quotes, there must have been something else. Maybe you had a non-printing character after the quotes that was deleted with them, for instance. Or maybe you had two single quotes and then a double (`echo ''"`) or something like that, but there had to be _something_ since `echo ""` is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link, you're right. Running `sudo echo` felt a bit weird.. And I'll try again on my linux install tonight and get back to comment here the results.

Answer (score 14):

This error can be hard to track in real situations. Here I provide one solution for real-world situations. I will use my script as an example.

I updated my shell script. When executing it I got the following error message:

```
/somepath/bin/myshellscript: line 1508: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/somepath/bin/myshellscript: line 1520: syntax error: unexpected end of file

line 1508 elif [ "$project" ]; then
```

This is the last line that has a pair of double quotes.

Normally, I check my shell script every time I modify it. This time, I waited for one day and forgot where I had made a modification.  The problem happened anywhere before this line (1508).  The problem is that even I commented outline 1508

```
#elif [ "$project" ]; then
```

the shell executioner still said line 1508 has trouble.

Next, I made a copy of the original shell script. Deleting a whole bunch of code from the bottom.  Then validate my code with the following command

```
bash -n mysbashscript

mybashscript: line 515: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
mybashscript: line 561: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Now my file is 1/3 of the original size. I immediately saw the problem:

```
497 prepare_alignment() {
498     local projdir=${1:?"did not give project directory"}
499     local samp=${2:?"did not give sample name"}
500     local merged=${3:?"must give merged bam file name} # here is the problem
```

For some reason, the unmatched `"` inside `{}` is not captured by the shell parser. This is where shell parser can be further improved.

The fastest algorithm to find the problem is to delete half of your code from the bottom, if the syntax error goes away, then it is in this half. If the syntax error is still there, the problem in the upper half.

If the problem in the latter half, undo the delete. Repeat this process. You can narrow down to a smaller size to find the source of the problem.

When deleting code, you have to delete a whole section of code. For example the whole function.

You can either use bash `-n script_name` or just directly execute the script. Both should work. (here script_name is just fooscript or barscript for illustration purpose not a real script name and should be one word).

Comment: "For some Reason, the unmatched " inside {} is not captured by the shell parser." Is that just because syntactically, it *is* matched, on line 1508? i.e. the string opened on line 500 is closed on line 1508, and then another string is opened on 1508 which never gets closed.

Comment: I did not investigate the quoting behavior of bash.  Bash may have multi-line quote "line1\nline2"  I remember in shell you do multi-line quote with <<ENDMARK. Possibly now you can directly use double quote to quote multiple lines.  This feature makes debug really hard.

Comment: I think its the best that you keep on taking backup of working copy of your script unless it gets completely ready.

Comment: Jaraws Yes, you could use source control (git) for long term tracking. For short term, don't just delete or edit lines immediately, make a copy and add comment mark at the beginning of the line.  The edit the copy of the line.  Some editors can recall you latest changes.

Comment: Quoting [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02): _The application shall quote the following characters if they are to represent themselves: [...] <newline>_ [Here-doc operator (`<<`)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) is about _redirection_, not quoting. It treats the enclosed text as a single word though.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error due to a missing curly bracket...

```
docker tag "${FOO" "${BOO}"
```

Comment: The curly brackets aren't required here, so you can remove them all

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to consider is that some key characters start a block and the double quote may not be the issue.  I wrap all my variables in bash in curly braces, but if you accidentally use a square bracket instead of a curly brace, this error pops up and the quotes all frustratingly line up.  Using Kemin Zhou's process, I was able to find this typo.  `echo "Starting $[report_name}" >> ${log}` looks a lot like `echo "Starting ${report_name}" >> ${log}`.  And the double quotes are NOT the issue, but are reported as such.