# bash bug - unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' on tab completion

Tags: bash, awk

I know this question has been answered many times like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154427/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-bash-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142936/bash-unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching).

But all of them had places where there was an extra erroneous quote.

I am just running a simple awk script in this fashion:

```
awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" copy.out
```

Now when I type until

```
awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" c #Press Tab after c
```

And press tab for tab completion I get the error:

```
awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" cbash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have the appropriate number of double quotes in my command. **I know this for sure because if I type out my file name without tab completion and then execute the command then it works fine.**

**What am I missing ?**

When I run `bash -x` and then do the above mentioned steps I get :

```
word split
+ _init_completion -s
+ local exclude= flag outx errx inx OPTIND=1
+ getopts n:e:o:i:s flag -s
+ case $flag in
+ split=false
+ exclude+==
+ getopts n:e:o:i:s flag -s
+ COMPREPLY=()
+ local 'redir=@(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)'
+ _get_comp_words_by_ref -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ local exclude flag i OPTIND=1
+ words=()
+ local cur cword words
+ upargs=()
+ upvars=()
+ local upargs upvars vcur vcword vprev vwords
+ getopts c:i:n:p:w: flag -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ case $flag in
+ exclude='=<>&'
+ getopts c:i:n:p:w: flag -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ [[ 6 -ge 3 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vcur=cur
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 4 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vprev=prev
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 5 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vwords=words
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 6 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vcword=cword
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 7 ]]
+ __get_cword_at_cursor_by_ref '=<>&' words cword cur
+ words=()
+ local cword words
+ __reassemble_comp_words_by_ref '=<>&' words cword
+ local exclude i j line ref
+ [[ -n =<>& ]]
+ exclude='=<>&'
+ printf -v cword %s 6
+ [[ -n =<>& ]]
+ line='awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ (( i=0, j=0 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 0 -gt 0 ]]
+ ref='words[0]'
+ printf -v 'words[0]' %s awk
+ line=' -f test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 0 == 6 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 1 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -f == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[1]'
+ printf -v 'words[1]' %s -f
+ line=' test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 1 == 6 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 2 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ test.awk == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[2]'
+ printf -v 'words[2]' %s test.awk
+ line=' -v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 2 == 6 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 3 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -v == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[3]'
+ printf -v 'words[3]' %s -v
+ line=' time="$t" c'
+ [[ 3 == 6 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 4 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ time == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[4]'
+ printf -v 'words[4]' %s time
+ line='="$t" c'
+ [[ 4 == 6 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 5 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ =" == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[5]'
+ printf -v 'words[5]' %s '="'
+ line='$t" c'
+ [[ 5 == 6 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 6 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ $t" c == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[6]'
+ printf -v 'words[6]' %s '$t" c'
+ line=
+ [[ 6 == 6 ]]
+ printf -v cword %s 6
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 7 == 6 ]]
+ local i cur index=30 'lead=awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 30 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -n awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" c ]]
+ [[ -n awk-ftest.awk-vtime="$t"c ]]
+ cur='awk -f test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ (( i = 0 ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 30 -ge 3 ]]
+ [[ awk != \a\w\k ]]
+ [[ 0 -lt 6 ]]
+ local old_size=30
+ cur=' -f test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ local new_size=27
+ index=27
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 27 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[  - != \-\f ]]
+ cur='-f test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 27 -gt 0 ]]
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 26 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ -f != \-\f ]]
+ [[ 1 -lt 6 ]]
+ local old_size=26
+ cur=' test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ local new_size=24
+ index=24
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 24 -ge 8 ]]
+ [[  test.aw != \t\e\s\t\.\a\w\k ]]
+ cur='test.awk -v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 24 -gt 0 ]]
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 23 -ge 8 ]]
+ [[ test.awk != \t\e\s\t\.\a\w\k ]]
+ [[ 2 -lt 6 ]]
+ local old_size=23
+ cur=' -v time="$t" c'
+ local new_size=15
+ index=15
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 15 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[  - != \-\v ]]
+ cur='-v time="$t" c'
+ [[ 15 -gt 0 ]]
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 14 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ -v != \-\v ]]
+ [[ 3 -lt 6 ]]
+ local old_size=14
+ cur=' time="$t" c'
+ local new_size=12
+ index=12
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 12 -ge 4 ]]
+ [[  tim != \t\i\m\e ]]
+ cur='time="$t" c'
+ [[ 12 -gt 0 ]]
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 11 -ge 4 ]]
+ [[ time != \t\i\m\e ]]
+ [[ 4 -lt 6 ]]
+ local old_size=11
+ cur='="$t" c'
+ local new_size=7
+ index=7
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 7 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ =" != \=\" ]]
+ [[ 5 -lt 6 ]]
+ local old_size=7
+ cur='$t" c'
+ local new_size=5
+ index=5
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 5 -ge 5 ]]
+ [[ $t" c != \$\t\"\ \c ]]
+ [[ 6 -lt 6 ]]
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ -n $t" c ]]
+ [[ ! -n $t"c ]]
+ [[ 5 -lt 0 ]]
+ local words cword cur
+ _upvars -a7 words awk -f test.awk -v time '="' '$t" c' -v cword 6 -v cur '$t" c'
+ ((  15  ))
+ ((  15  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n 7 ]]
+ printf %d 7
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ unset -v words
+ eval 'words=("${@:3:7}")'
++ words=("${@:3:7}")
+ shift 9
+ ((  6  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ unset -v cword
+ eval 'cword="$3"'
++ cword=6
+ shift 3
+ ((  3  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ unset -v cur
+ eval 'cur="$3"'
++ cur='$t" c'
+ shift 3
+ ((  0  ))
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ upvars+=("$vcur")
+ upargs+=(-v $vcur "$cur")
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ upvars+=("$vcword")
+ upargs+=(-v $vcword "$cword")
+ [[ -n prev ]]
+ [[ 6 -ge 1 ]]
+ upvars+=("$vprev")
+ upargs+=(-v $vprev "${words[cword - 1]}")
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ upvars+=("$vwords")
+ upargs+=(-a${#words[@]} $vwords "${words[@]}")
+ ((  4  ))
+ local cur cword prev words
+ _upvars -v cur '$t" c' -v cword 6 -v prev '="' -a7 words awk -f test.awk -v time '="' '$t" c'
+ ((  18  ))
+ ((  18  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ unset -v cur
+ eval 'cur="$3"'
++ cur='$t" c'
+ shift 3
+ ((  15  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ unset -v cword
+ eval 'cword="$3"'
++ cword=6
+ shift 3
+ ((  12  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n prev ]]
+ unset -v prev
+ eval 'prev="$3"'
++ prev='="'
+ shift 3
+ ((  9  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n 7 ]]
+ printf %d 7
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ unset -v words
+ eval 'words=("${@:3:7}")'
++ words=("${@:3:7}")
+ shift 9
+ ((  0  ))
+ _variables
+ [[ $t" c =~ ^(\$(\{[!#]?)?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ ]]
+ [[ $t" c =~ ^(\$\{[#!]?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)\[([^]]*)$ ]]
+ [[ $t" c =~ ^\$\{[#!]?[A-Za-z0-9_]*\[.*]$ ]]
+ case $prev in
+ return 1
+ [[ $t" c == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ [[ =" == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&) ]]
+ local i skip
+ (( i=1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ -f == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=2
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ test.awk == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=3
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ -v == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=4
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ time == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=5
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ =" == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=6
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ $t" c == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=7
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 7 ))
+ [[ 6 -le 0 ]]
+ prev='="'
+ [[ -n false ]]
+ _split_longopt
+ [[ $t" c == --?*=* ]]
+ return 1
+ return 0
+ case "${prev,,}" in
+ false
+ [[ $t" c == -* ]]
+ [[ awk == @(rmdir|chroot) ]]
+ [[ awk == mkdir ]]
+ _filedir
+ local 'IFS=
'
+ _tilde '$t" c'
+ local result=0
+ [[ $t" c == \~* ]]
+ return 0
+ local -a toks
+ local x tmp
++ compgen -d -- '$t" c'
+ x=
+ [[ '' != -d ]]
+ local quoted
+ _quote_readline_by_ref '$t" c' quoted
+ '[' -z '$t" c' ']'
+ [[ $t" c == \'* ]]
+ [[ $t" c == \~* ]]
+ printf -v quoted %q '$t" c'
+ [[ \$t\"\ c == *\\* ]]
+ printf -v quoted %s '$t" c'
+ [[ $t" c == \$* ]]
+ eval 'quoted=$t" c'
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
+ local xspec=
++ compgen -f -X '' -- '$t" c'
+ x=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
```

The last lines it says `unquoted $t"` but I do provide the full quotes and it does work. So isn't this some kind of bug ? I mean bash took the liberty to ignore or incorrectly parse my starting quote

Comment: This error is from some bash script being run when you press tab (probably from bash-completion), not awk. What does running bash as `bash -x` say around the error?

Comment: @ChrisDown Can you please explain a little bit about what `bash -x` does ? Then I can give you better information and also learn.

Comment: It outputs each thing which is being executed and will likely show the source of your problem. Once you get a prompt, try performing the repro steps again and look at what's immediately before this error.

Comment: @ChrisDown I have edited the question to include the output of `bash -x`, it did include my `awk` script so I don't think this is entirely unrelated to `awk`.

Comment: @ChrisDown Wait, isn't this a bug? I mean in the last lines it says `unquoted $t"` but I do provide the full quotes and it does work. So isn't this some kind of bug ? I mean bash took the liberty to ignore or incorrectly parse my starting quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `bash -x` output, you have found a bug in the bash-completion package (which is not part of `bash`, but is a community-maintained package of tab completions). Your issue is the bash completion run in this case doesn't properly escape quoting when passing to `eval`:

```
+ printf -v quoted %s '$t" c'
+ [[ $t" c == \$* ]]
+ eval 'quoted=$t" c'
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Looking at the bug tracker, this looks to be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1312243), which has already been fixed upstream, but the patch hasn't made it into your repos yet.

You have a few options:

1. Find a backport of bash-completion for your distribution. It's not mentioned what distribution that is in your question, but on Ubuntu for example, you may be able to find a new version in a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas).
2. Stop using the bash-completion package and just use bash's internal completion logic. Depending on what you need tab completion to do, this might be adequate.
3. Wait it out for the fix to enter your distribution's repositories. Depending on your distribution the time it may take for the fix to make it there may vary from "in 5 minutes" to "never".
4. If your distribution has a process around backporting upstream fixes, you may consider requesting a backport of the patch for this fix to be applied, instead of waiting for the new version. Depending on the maintainer and distribution's policy, this may or may not work.

Comment: Good to know it really was a bug and not me just being a linux noob.